I am having issue in Next.js
I am having error :
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
at Object.relative (node:path:502:5)
at Watchpack. (D:\MyProjects\workspace\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:381:55) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
while running command npm run dev in my next js project
Anyone help me to resolve this issue
I have tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json but issue still persist

Its not the issue with node_modules.
Go to this file
node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js
Go to line number 381
Add some logs like below.
This will provide you details what path is exactly conflicting.
Go to that folder and fix issue. Remove logs
               for (const p of conflictingAppPagePaths){
                    console.log('dir', dir);
                    console.log('path', appPageFilePaths);
                    console.log('conflicting path', p);
                    const appPath = _path.default.relative(dir, appPageFilePaths.get(p));
                    const pagesPath = _path.default.relative(dir, pagesPageFilePaths.get(p));
                    errorMessage += `  "${pagesPath}" - "${appPath}"\n`;
                }

